# How can I alter my program for the desired output?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am trying to write a program that takes user input for the number of hours worked by 6 employees  of a company to store in a two-dimensional array and prints the output in the following format:

```
Employee Number        Hours
01                      a
02                      b
03                      c
04                      d
05                      e
06                      f
```

where a-f would be the user entered integer values.

I have experimented with several methods but am unable to get my desired output. I am attaching the recent attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int array[6][2]; // 6 by 2 matrix to store employee name and hours worked
    int i, j;

    cout << "Enter the number of hours worked by 6 employees: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            cin >> array[i][j];
            cout << array[i][j] << "\t" << endl;
            break;
        }
        cout << endl;

    }
}
```

What changes should I make to get the required output?

Comment: what is your cuurent output?

Comment: why is there are unconditional `break` in the inner loop?

Comment: Why is there a `break` condition? As there is a `break` condition so you can only take one number in that loop. Remove the `break` condition.

Comment: @FarukHossain okay, but the errors still stay.

Comment: Okay. Posting a answer which should serve your expectation.

Comment: Is employee Number integer value? or string?

Comment: @FarukHossain integer

Comment: @solopolo, posted answer. Does this satisfy your expectation?

Answer (score 1):

You should take the input first. Then in order to print with column name you should first print those column names and then print the values.
Your code should be like this -

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int array[6][2]; // 6 by 2 matrix to store employee name and hours worked
    int i, j;

    cout << "Enter the number of hours worked by 6 employees: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            cin >> array[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << "Employee Number \t Hours" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            cout << array[i][j] << "\t\t\t   ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Edit:
For your requirement from the comment, new code will be

```
int main()
{
    int array[6][2]; // 6 by 2 matrix to store employee name and hours worked
    int i, j;

    cout << "Enter the number of hours worked by 6 employees: " << endl;
    cout << "Employee Number \t Hours" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            cin >> array[i][j];
            cout << array[i][j] << "\t\t\t   ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }


}
```

[image: picture]

Comment: I have a question tho, is it possible to get the number of employees printed without entering them first. By maybe getting the value of "i" printed throughout its 6 iterations?

Comment: In that case you should get the second image.